# Add bluetooth mouse to Windows 10 after removing it

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I accidentally removed my Microsoft Bluetooth Mouse from the Windows 10 Bluetooth settings. Now it doesn't appear at all in Manage Bluetooth Devices. Any idea how to get it back please?

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft, you need to:

1. Turn on your device and make it discoverable. (The way you make it discoverable depends on the device. Check the device or visit the manufacturer's website to learn how.)
2. On the taskbar, select action center > Connect > the device name.

[image]

3. Follow any more instructions that might appear. Otherwise, you're
   done and connected.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/getstarted-connect-to-bluetooth-devices)

Comment: Great. Please mark the answer as accepted so others will know the question has been answered. :)